# stack install executable to a custom location

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I usually do `stack install <package-name>` and Stack installs it in the location `~/.local/bin`.

Is there a way for me to specify the destination location ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `--local-bin-path` to specify your custom destination path. Demo:

```
$ stack install tldr --local-bin-path /home/sibi
Copying from /home/sibi/github/tldr-hs/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-12.10/8.4.3/bin/tldr to /home/sibi/tldr

Copied executables to /home/sibi:
- tldr

Warning: Installation path /home/sibi not found on the PATH environment variable.
$ ls -lh /home/sibi/tldr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sibi sibi 3.0M Dec 23 01:37 /home/sibi/tldr
```

Comment: Any idea how to use customized executable name?

Comment: @elliptic00 You can change the executable name in `package.yaml` under `executables`